# Run job inside docker container in specific agent Jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to run the Jenkins pipeline steps in the Docker container in a specific agent.
I could use docker to run it but the container will run in a random agent but i need it to run in specific agent.

Here's what i tried:

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'agent-007' }

    stages {            
        stage("Unit Tests") {
          agent { docker 'image-name' }
          steps {
            sh 'pwd'
            sh 'hostname'
          }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation [Specifying a Docker Label](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/) it says that in the configuration for your Jenkins job, you can specify which agent you want docker to run on. In your case, you could set "Docker Label" to "agent-007" in your job configuration. You can also specify which docker registry you want to pull from which is really handy if you use Artifactory, for instance.